# How to save image added in a Google Sheet cell to Google Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a google sheet that is to be used by a third person. 
The sheet contains a column that requires them to upload an image into the cell (using Google Sheets Image In Cell feature). 
I want to be able to via Google Apps Script, save these images, with an appropriate name based on a value in the row, to a folder in my Google Drive.
Is this possible?

Comment: If the image is put with the formula of `=IMAGE(URL)`, you can retrieve the image from the URL. But in the current stage, unfortunately. the image directly put in a cell without the formula cannot be retrieved using Google Apps Script. And also, even when the image is put on the sheet, the blob of image cannot be retrieved. Although this might be modified in the future, unfortunately, this is the current answer. I'm sorry for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tanaike said, there is currently no way to do that automatically unless you get the URL and doesnt work on generated images (like QR codes) either. Not even right click works for such.

Externally, the only solution for the moment would be to manually get a screen capture (the 'recortes' tool in Windows can help). To automate this you could do a script to move the browser, then take a capture and save it, then move the browser again, rinse and repeat , but still there is no direct solution inside Google Sheets.